# impossible to work with opportunity product schedules in the Salesforce1 app?

Tags: salesforce1-app, opportunity-lineitem, opp-lineitemschedule

We have opportunity product scheduling enabled on our org.
This is all working fine.

Now, we are about to open up the Salesforce1 app for our users and were doing some checks of what was working out-of-the-box and what not.

To my surprise, I saw that the opportunity product scheduling is not working on the Salesforce1 mobile app.

2 scenario's I tested:

- just trying to update the price of an existing opportunity product that had a schedule : the system seemed to allow me to just update the Sales Price. Doing so however resulted in nothing. (no updated sales price)
- created an action to add a new opportunity product to an opportunity : seemed to work... however, the product that was added only had the "Sales Price" filled... No schedule records were created. In the normal web interface, this does work and create schedules.

Anyone else had the same requirement? (editing products & schedules on the Salesforce1 app) How did you solve it?

Answer (score 1):

It's been confirmed by Salesforce that this is a bug and that they will pick this up as part of the roadmap.

So, if you are using scheduling for your opportunity lines, adding / editing prices of your products will not behave as expected.